# Bind Command to KeyBinding in Code Behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I want to add some generic keyboard shortcuts to my application. Currently, in every View XAML I add this code:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding ZoomInCommand}" Key="Add" Modifiers="Control" />
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding ZoomOutCommand}" Key="Subtract" Modifiers="Control" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

I order to generalize this, I want to subclass the WPF Window Class and use the newly created subclass instead. Now I'm wondering how I could bind these Keyboard commands in the corresponding code. Currently it looks like this:

```
public class MyWindow : Window
{
    public MyWindow()
    {
        DataContextChanged += OnDataContextChanged;
    }

    private void OnDataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        InputBindings.Clear();
        var dataContext = DataContext as IZoomableViewModel;
        if (dataContext != null)
        {
            InputBindings.Add(new KeyBinding(dataContext.ZoomInCommand, Key.Add, ModifierKeys.Control));
            InputBindings.Add(new KeyBinding(dataContext.ZoomOutCommand, Key.Subtract, ModifierKeys.Control));
        }
    }
}
```

But this doesn't look right to me, as I need to have access to the DataContext directly and cast it instead of using a Binding() Object. How can I change the code to make it look more MVVM-like?

Answer (score 3):

I found a simple solution which works nicely and seems to imitate the XAML parser behavior. Basically, for the zoom in functionality I put the following code in the MyWindow constructor:

```
var zoomInKeyBinding = new KeyBinding { Key = Key.Add, Modifiers = ModifierKeys.Control };
BindingOperations.SetBinding(
    zoomInKeyBinding,
    InputBinding.CommandProperty,
    new Binding { Path = new PropertyPath("ZoomInCommand") }
);
InputBindings.Add(zoomInKeyBinding);
```

Of course the bound ViewModel needs to implement the ZoomInCommand appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

What you need are **Dependency Properties**.

In `MyWindow`, create an `ICommand` dependency property for **both** of your commands, you will also need to implement a **callback** method for when the dependency property value changes, here's one for the `ZoomInCommand`:

```
public ICommand ZoomInCommand
{
    get { return (ICommand)GetValue(ZoomInCommandProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ZoomInCommandProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ZoomInCommand.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty ZoomInCommandProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ZoomInCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(MyWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnZoomInCommandChanged)));

...

private static void OnZoomInCommandChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MyWindow wnd = (MyWindow)d;

    //Remove the old key binding if there is one.
    wnd.RemoveInputBinding(e.OldValue as ICommand);

    //Add the new input binding.
    if (e.NewValue != null)
        wnd.InputBindings.Add(new KeyBinding((ICommand)e.NewValue, Key.Add, ModifierKeys.Control));
}

private void RemoveInputBinding(ICommand command)
{
    if (command == null)
        return;

    //Find the old binding if there is one.
    InputBinding oldBinding = null;

    foreach (InputBinding binding in InputBindings)
    {
        if (binding.Command == command)
        {
            oldBinding = binding;
            break;
        }
    }

    //Remove the old input binding.
    if (oldBinding != null)
        InputBindings.Remove(oldBinding);
}
```

So what exactly does the code above do?

On the dependency property, it is optional to have a `PropertyChangedCallback` method which will fire whenever the property value changes, this is great because we can use this to **remove** the old `InputBinding` and create a new `InputBinding` if the value were to change. In your case, the value will change whenever the `DataContext` changes.

So the steps are quite simple, whenever the property value changes:

1. Remove the old `InputCommand` for the old `ICommand`.
2. Add a new `InputCommand` for the new `ICommand`.

I've create a handy `RemoveInputBinding` method which should make it easier to reuse the code for your other dependency property, which is up to you to implement.

---

To fit this all together, in your `DataContextChanged` event handler you simply need to write a **manual** binding:

```
private void MyWindow_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //Bind this.ZoomInCommand to DataContext.ZoomInCommand
    Binding zoomInCommandBinding = new Binding("ZoomInCommand");
    zoomInCommandBinding.Source = DataContext;
    this.SetBinding(MyWindow.ZoomInCommandProperty, zoomInCommandBinding);

    ...
}
```

This will ensure that you no longer need to worry about casting the `DataContext` to an `IZoomableViewModel`, you simply *try* to bind to the `ZoomInCommand`. If there is no such command in the `DataContext`, then it will just silently fail. If it does succeed however, the `PropertyChangedCallback` will be fired and an `InputBinding` will be created for the command.